# listening for click event for an href by classname

Tags: javascript, html, href, event-listener

there is a page with some basic HTML that I cannot touch that looks like this:

```
<a class="continue-shopping" href="https://someURL">Continue shopping</a>
```

what I want to do is send the user to a different link when they click on the someURL text link.  the user can come to a page containing this html from many other pages.

i have tried many hours but cannot get my js to recognize a click event for a class associated with hyperlinked text.  i could really use some help here.  this is the js code i wrote which does not work

```
window.onload = function() {
prepEventHandler();
```

}

```
function prepEventHandler () {

var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName("continue-shopping");

myClass[0].onclick=window.open(document.referrer,"_self");

/*  which make my pages go haywire OR THIS -- which also does not work */


 myClass[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
 window.open(document.referrer,"_self");
 }
 )
}
```

It just keeps ignoring the second function, and I am sure I am doing some really basic that is wrong.  Again, thanks for any help!

Comment: `myClass[0].onclick=function(){window.open(document.referrer,"_self");return false;};`

The return false is almost an old-fashioned "prevent-default"

Comment: @SparK : `return false` = `event.prevetDefault()` + `event.stopPropagation()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1055987

Comment: @JFK From the link you posted: `Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, return false does not stop the event from bubbling up.`... so `return false` = `event.preventDefault()`;

Comment: @SparK : you are correct, however in a non-jQuery context `preventDefault` is not an old-fashioned `return false;` in that case it would be the other way around

Comment: @JFK which is what I stated in the first comment XD

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `preventDefault()` you could also use `return false`

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myClass = document.querySelector(".continue-shopping")
        .onclick = function () {
        window.location.href = "http://elsewere.com";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow. u guys are really good at this.  again, many thx!  i dont know enough js yet to determine which is the preferable method!

Comment: Depends on what side-effect you want:

* The onclick will override the previous onclick listener.
* The addEventListener method will just add another listener without erasing the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

this code should work but it no longer does and i do not know why  any hint much appreciated - there seems to be some problem with myClass[0]

```
window.onload = function() {

    var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('continue-shopping'); 

    myClass[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
        });
    }
```